# .htaccess is ignored even if rightly configured

Tags: linux, .htaccess, apache-2.4, htpasswd

I am getting mad:

- vhost: http://termbin.com/4z10

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:8080>
>   ServerAdmin istreaming@gmail.com
>   ServerName ec2-52-36-220-163.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
>
>   DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
>   <Directory />
>       Options FollowSymLinks
>       AllowOverride None
>   </Directory>
>
>   <Directory /var/www/wordress>
>       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>       AllowOverride None
>       Order allow,deny
>       allow from all
>   </Directory>
>
> #mariadb
>   <Directory /var/www/wordress/mydbadmin>
>           AllowOverride AuthConfig
>           # The Options below is an example. Use what you deem is necessary.
>           Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
>           Order allow,deny
>           Allow from all
>   </Directory>
>
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- htaccess: http://termbin.com/kjw1

> ```
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName "Authentication Required"
> AuthUserFile "/var/www/wordpress/mydbadmin/.htpasswd"
> Require valid-user
> ```

- htpasswd: http://termbin.com/3dwr
- doc: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth

Ignore the bunk in htaccess, was trying to generate an error to see of it was not being read.

Comment: what about a) logs? b) httpd.conf?

Comment: Are you running the server? Are you allowed to modify the main config file? Because, if so, you [shouldn't be using htaccess files, anyway](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) (direct quote from the docs: "You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.").

Answer (score 0):

The directory you are declaring (`/var/www/wordress/mydbadmin`) doesn't exist and so nothing is happening. It's a typing mistake I guess. Correct it, `wordress` -> `wordpress` (`/var/www/wordpress/mydbadmin`) and see.

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/mydbadmin>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        # The Options below is an example. Use what you deem is necessary.
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```